# select row data from javascript function parsing html source

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json

I want to parse json code embedded inside html source under js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     someFunction({             
          data: [{"Href":"http://someimg.jpg"}]
     });
</script>
```

I've found the way how to parse json from but I dont know how to select data from someFunction inside variable to operate further.

Comment: can you post some more detailed code

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON.parse(data);

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
             var jsonParsedContent;
             someFunction({             
                  data: [{"Href":"http://someimg.jpg"}];
                  jsonParsedContent = JSON.parse(data);
             });
            alert(jsonParsedContent[0]);
        </script>
```

This will return the first element in your json.

Comment: great, but how can I use jsonParsedContent = JSON.parse(data); outside js function, cause I'm getting whole page html source inside one string variable?

Comment: make your jsonParseContent variable global, than you will be able to use anywhere inside the script.